# react native maps moving without user input

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

This is my MapView code,

```
        <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={
        this.state.region 
      }
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
      showsMyLocationButton
      showsCompass
      showsUserLocation 
      zoomControlEnabled 
      loadingEnabled
      onMapReady={this.state.placesread ? this.getBreakfast : null}
    >
      {marker}
    </MapView>
```

My problem is when user moves the map position the map starts randomly moving around without stopping, and it cannot be stopped without closing the map window.

when the map loads i get markers and load on the map and similar to google maps i have a search this area button on the map, i am using the `onRegionChangeComplete` to store the new region to state.

my `onRegionChangeComplete` code is,

```
  onRegionChange = async region => {
await this.setState({ region });
await this.setState({ regionChange: true });
```

};

Comment: Please share  `onRegionChangeComplete` function code

Comment: @Shivam I've updated my answer

Comment: I have posted the answer let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using `onRegionChangeComplete` callback to store the new region to state. i.e `this.state.region`. and that `region` prop is passed to `MapView` Component.

Try removing `region={this.state.region}` from `MapView` component.

**Update**

Also one more thing using `await` with `setState` is totally redundant(`await this.setState({ region })`) because setSate does not return `promise` but `undefined`.

`setState` is asynchronous function. If you want to await it what you can do is you can put it into a promise and resolve in callback/second argument.

For Example whenever you want `setState` to behave as synchronous call `promisedSetState` like so.

```
promisedSetState = (newState) => new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.setState(newState, () => {
            resolve();
        });
});
//await the promise to get resolved
await promisedSetState({newState: 'whatever it is'});
```